# Java GUI bringing up previous window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener

simple question here but can't find any resources to help me.

In an `ActionListener` I've made I bring up a new window. I've guessed you keep the main window visibility to false. but how do I close the newly opened window  and set the visibility of the old window back to true?

here is my main window which brings up the new window.

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         window.setVisible(false);
         Clock clock = new Clock(initialSize);
         while(clock.isVisible()){
             window.setVisible(false);
         }
         window.setVisible(true);                   
     } 
 });
```

and here is my new windows `ActonListener` which closes that one and opens old window.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ea){    
     jframe.setVisible(false);
 }
```

I'm new to this, so it may be an obvious answer here which I am unaware of. the current code here is a desperate attempt. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but how do I close the newly opened window and set the visibility of
>   the old window back to true?

- add [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to [JFrame/JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)
- override [windowClosing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) event, here you can to call `setVisible(false)` for `JDialog` and `setVisible(true)` for `JFrame`
- change default close operation for JFrame/JDialog to [HIDE or NOTHING_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29)
- [setParent for JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog%29)